# How to parse a report using Shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I have a command line program that prints out a report such as:

```
I found 0 problems on your database,
0 problems were found on your database
```

and so on.

I would like to write a linux shell script that exports the number only to a variable. I can't find the correct way of doing so. I suspect I am not using `grep` properly (or there's a better command);
i.e.

```
I found 43 problems on your database,
43 problems were found on your database
$VAR=43
```

please advise

Comment: are you get 2 lines of output or many lines?

Comment: Learn to use and combine `awk`  and `grep`, and perhaps some scripting language like `python`, `ocaml`, `ruby`, or `perl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ var=$(echo -e "I found 43 problems on your database,
43 problems were found on your database" | grep -om 1 '[0-9]\+')
$ echo $var
43
```

Comment: Cool! Now: sometimes it gives me "I found X blah blah blah [newline] problem [newline] problem [etc.] x problems were foud. i want to take the number from the last line and not the first. is there a way of doing so?

Comment: @user1461638 Try changing `grep -om 1 '[0-9]\+'` to `grep -o '[0-9]\+' | tail -1`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from Lev Levitsky perfect, but I just want to add that in case when your report contains many such lines with numbers and you want to process each of them, you will use something like:

```
cat report | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | while read var
do
  # do something with var
done
```